# Shell extensions in .NET with administrator privileges

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, administrator, shell-extensions

I have some shell extensions written in .NET 4.5 and they work perfectly fine except when they need administrator privileges. For example, suppose I need my shell extension to operate on a file in `C:\Program Files\` and create a new file in the same folder. This would require administrator privileges and the code just silently fails.

I can think of a workaround: wrapping any admin elevated code in an exe with the appropriate `app.manifest` to have admin rights and calling `Process.Start(..)` on that exe.

But this is a lot of hassle if there is another way.

It wouldn't be surprising if this is not allowed in Windows, but I cannot find any documentation to suggest that this is the case.

Comment: In-process shell extensions run in the Windows Explorer process, so they have the same permissions as explorer.exe... I'm pretty sure there is no way around it, unless you start explorer.exe as admin.

Comment: I haven't written shell extensions in a few years, but doing that in .net has a few disadvantages - shell extensions should never block execution (which is more problematic in managed world) and loading.net shell extension may cause a crash if e.g. .net 1.1 is already present there. Remember that your extension is loaded into every process that opens file open dialog. The most sensible architecture imho is write thin C++ extension that talks to .net app. This will also help you with the original problem. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @MichalMa - thanks for the reply :) things have changed since .NET 4 and it is now safe and even encouraged to write managed shell extensions due to a change with .NET 4 in how it can operate side-by-side with different versions of .NET. For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx (specifically the section titled "Shell Extension Developers")

Comment: Thanks for the info. It definitely looks safer, however I still bet money that application written in .net 1.1 will blow up if your extension is loaded. This is probably rare enough to ignore in your case.

Comment: No, that is precisely the problem they addressed with .NET 4. You can run .NET 4 and 1.1 side by side and it will not blow up. You can run .NET 4 and .NET 3.5 side by side. What you still can't do is run any two versions of .NET from 3.5 and under side by side.